# Determine what APPS are Android Auto Compatible

Tags: google-play-store, android-auto

When I connect my cell phone to my vehicle, Android Auto displays a very limited list of APPs that are on my phone:

[image]

(The clipped APP at the bottom is weather).

Supposedly more APPs that are compatible with that interface will be released.

How do I determine if an APP on Google Play is compatible? I don't see anything on the Google Play webpage for a given APP that indicates it can be used or not used for Android Auto.

(In particular, I want navigation with offline maps beyond what Google Maps offers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a special category in Google Play Store that lists apps ready for Android Auto:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_3001303_android_auto_all

If you have an APK and want to check if it is ready for Android Auto you can look at it's AndroidManifest.xml file inside the APK. It should contain an entry like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application" android:resource="...."/>
```

For more details see [Add support for Android Auto to your media app](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto).